# What have been Trump's successful policies/reforms?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, economy, policy, foreign-policy

Honestly, I'm not personally inclined to support Trump because his rhetoric and misinformation tactics rub me the wrong the way, but I make a point to consume centered media as often as I can and I genuinely don't tend to hear much about any "good" Trump has done for the country while in office. Trump supporters that I talk to say this is because "the media is against/attacking Trump," and while and I can concede that maybe NPR isn't as centered as I thought, I think it may also be because he makes a good headline.

I think if I knew more about his policy, I might have a more nuanced/less emotionally charged view of him, which is very valuable to me. I honestly don't know how else to attempt to inform myself about this unbiasedly because of how politically/emotionally charged it can get.

1. Is the media underreporting Trump's success? or I am just listening to/reading left leaning media without knowing (NPR, Bloomberg, BBC Global)?
2. I would appreciate some bullet points about his economic policy, social reform, and foreign policy, but add anything you think is important. I intent to use this as a jumpstart for further research.

Comment: I was sure there was a question a while back about which of Trump's policies he had successfully implemented, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Related economy, [Which policies has Trump enacted that has (possibly) influenced the GDP and economy positively?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/23232/26455)

Comment: @CDJB That's the one I was trying to find earlier, good job.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the fact that this question is marked as a duplicate of a *closed* question. How does that make sense? Either we should remove the duplicate tag, or reopen the other question.

Comment: By "successful" do you mean that the administration succeded in implementing the policy or that the policy was beneficial?  The first comment above assumes the former, but the second comment assumes the latter.  Without making this clear in the question, confusing and conflicting answers are probably guaranteed.  The second question is, of course, much more difficult to treat objectively.  Furthermore, your question suggests the second interpretation by mentioning "'any 'good' Trump has done for the country," while the answers take the first interpretation.

Comment: Downvoted because any answer would be subjective.

Answer (score 6):

We can go straight to the horse's mouth (as it were) and look at the [Trump administration's claims of accomplishment](https://www.whitehouse.gov/trump-administration-accomplishments/) on whitehouse.gov. The page itself is amateurish — a set of bullet points with no structure, a lot of redundancy, and the occasional lapse into a carnival barker's tone ("SEE the great accomplishments!!!") — but seems like an accurate (if loose) reflection of the administration's achievements.

If I were to impose structure on it, I would break the list down into the following sections:

- Economic

  - Employment benchmarks for various minority groups
  - Increases in the manufacturing and retail sectors, and in exports, particularly in coal and gas
  - Tax cuts
- Immigration

  - Various travel bans, restrictions, and the beginnings of The Wall
- Foreign policy

  - Withdrawal from Paris Climate Accord, Iran Deal, NAFTA (though reaching a new deal with Mexico in the last case)
  - Various tariffs on various governments for various reasons
- Domestic

  - Removal of various regulations (including and specifically the Clean Power Plan)
  - Securing an increased military budget
  - Appointment of numerous judges

All told, much of his term has been spent undoing the efforts of previous administrations (particularly the Obama administration), and advancing isolationist policy. Many of the things Trump claims as *positive* achievements were *passive* achievements — things that happened without any overt action or messaging on Trump's part, such as the economic benchmarks and increases — making it unclear whether they relate to Trump's administration or are ongoing reflections of Obama's recovery program from the 2008 economic collapse. In any case, most of these passive achievements have been gutted by Trump's response to the coronavirus pandemic, though naturally that isn't reflected on a partisan page of this sort.

Comment: But why should we be expected to believe the White House claims?

Comment: Some of them are factual; some exaggerations; some pure fabrications. I think anyone who tries can see the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Since  @yannis removed my comments and wants me to post it as an answer, here it is:

1. Trump moved the United States Israeli embassy to Jerusalem and facilitated the first Israel-Arab peace deal in 26 years. He also replaced NAFTA - that is in the foreign policy. There are also deals with N. Korea and China but this is in progress. Same is with respect to Iran. ISIS is basically dead, which is also a success.
2. Trump signed a Criminal Justice Reform act - that is social policy.
3. Trump administration enabled a large Tax cut - that is economics policy. There are other things too: regulations, stock market growth, etc.

Comment: 1) He didn't replace NAFTA, he unilaterally nuked it and is trying to renegotiate a better deal despite having little to offer. The "deal" with NK is a joke that absolutely no one takes seriously, and he started a trade war with China by repeatedly shooting himself in the foot. He also unilaterally broke a treaty with Iran that had strong international support and was widely seen as finally making some actual progress, and despite claims of ISIS' demise the whole middle east hasn't gotten any safer.

Comment: 3) The tax cut was basically a 1.5 trillion dollar giveaway to rich corporations, which immediately used it not to create jobs or improve the economy, but to buy back stocks which made their billionaire investors richer but doesn't do much for anyone else.

Comment: @Shadur: I do not know who you are. If you live in the US, it probably benefited you too.  Did you give your money to rich corporations? It certainly benefited me and I am neither rich nor a corporation. But all this is totally irrelevant to the question. The tax cut was a success. Trump promised it and delivered.

Comment: @JCAA speaking for myself, as a senior with income less than 100K, the Trump Tax Cut had an immediate impact on me - it increased my tax bill. If there were other benefits (to me) I have not observed them yet.

Comment: @BobE: Are you saying that all seniors with income less than 100K lost money?

Comment: @Shadur: FYI: NAFTA has been replaced by USMCA.

Comment: @JCAA no that would be presumptuous, however the elimination of SALT coupled with the elimination of the personal exemption for myself and my wife (~8,000$) resulted in a increased tax liability for my family and several others that I have talked with. .  But no, I can not say "All"

Comment: I noticed SALT reduction elimination too. But it did not affect me much. Also this text claims that SALT reduction only benefits the rich and should be eliminated https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/09/04/the-salt-tax-deduction-is-a-handout-to-the-rich-it-should-be-eliminated-not-expanded/

Comment: I don't know anything about new proposals to lift the SALT cap that is being discussed. All I know is that the impact of SALT and the personal exemptions resulted in a several percent increase in my tax bills for  2017 18 19 (when all other taxable events remained unchanged).

Comment: @BobE: I am almost a senior too. But for the last 3 years the stock market was doing so well that the little changes in the Tax code did not affect me at all. And I almost never claimed SALT before.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at it from a total wealth standpoint. When your investments are in an IRA and you are just taking your MRD (after you've reached 70.5), you will find that the actual/real income from those investments is fairly stable. That is to say that a 25% increase in your portfolio, does not mean that your RMD income for that year increases by 25%. In other words, unless you regularly cash-out your stock market gains, those gains are just chips let on the roulette table - subject to the next spin of the wheel.

Comment: @BobE: That is true.

Comment: But to the extent that any of the things on that list were actually done, by what OBJECTIVE standard could they reasonably be called accomplishments?  As the comments so far make clear, any benefit from Trump administration actions seems completely subjective.

Comment: @jamesqf: I suspect that you are not ready to call anything related to  Trump "accomplishment". But here you go:

 #1 is certainly a great accomplishment. It is  much bigger than Clinton's Oslo accord. And Bill Clinton tried very hard as you may know.

About 2 - since I have not, fortunately, any interaction with the Justice system, I do not know. But Trump promised it in 2016 and he delivered. Compare  this with Obama's promise to close Gitmo "in his first day in office". 

About 3 I have written already. By the way, inspite of the virus, the stocks keep going up.

Comment: @JCAA: How can moving an embassy 33 miles/55 km at a cost to US taxpayers of over $21 million objectively be deemed an accomplishment?  https://www.businessinsider.com/how-much-did-the-us-embassy-in-jerusalem-cost-2018-7  As for "facilitating" a peace deal, that is simply Trump taking credit for something he basically had nothing to do with.  "Replacing NAFTA" can be seen as trying to wreck the economy and increase illegal immigration.  The "peace deal" with North Korea was basically Trump kissing that fat kid's butt.  ISIS was done by the US military (and others) despite Trump's interference.